# How do I deliver OpenAL32.dll with my application without requiring OpenAL installation on the client machine?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, openal

I have a 32-bit C++ Windows application using the OpenAL library. I am using the official OpenAL setup to install the required DLL file, but when I publish my application, I would like to find a way to deliver it without requiring the user to install OpenAL seperately like I did.

With other DLL files, I simply add them to my project, but with OpenAL I seemed to get issues. Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: You can typically build installers for required components into your program's installer. This removes the need for a separate installation step.

Comment: Is it possible to compile using Static libraries of OpenAL so you don't need DLL for distribution?

Comment: Use an installer like NSIS to package the dll dependency along with your executable.

Comment: ***OpenAL I seemed to get issues*** You may want to explain exactly what issues you had.

Comment: There is OpenAL and OpenAL-soft. The former is proprietary I think? The latter is free&open-source and doesn' need an installer, you just distribute a dll along with you exe.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I am using OpenAL-Soft. Now, I link `OpenAL32.lib` and renamed the `soft_oal.dll` to `OpenAL32.dll` and put it in the execution directory, like I've read. It compiles, but it gives an error at the very first line: `AL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Do you know how I can make this work?

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am working with Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Ok, did you download prebuilt openal? Or built it yourself?

Comment: I am using prebuilt. When I install OpenAL from the official download page, it works, but once I copy the `OpenAL32.dll` from my `System32` folder to my executable directory and uninstall OpenAL from programs, it stops working

Comment: @HolyBlackCat by the way, I am building x86 on an x64 machine. I am trying to use the Win32 libs and bins, is that correct?

Comment: 1. *"from my System32 folder"* Why was it there to begin with? You shouldn't put anything there. 2. Yes, the bitness of the libs should match what you're compiling for, your OS bitness doesn't matter. 3. I suggest searching for any other copies `OpenAL32.dll` that could be in the PATH, and could be interfering. Or, if everything else fails, I'd try to rebuild openal myself, just in case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, I mixed up the System32 and SysWow64 folders in Windows.

It should be the other way around!

- **System32** on 64-bit Windows contains **64**-bit `.dll` files
- **SysWow64** on 64-bit Windows contains **32**-bit `.dll` files

For reference:
https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/

**What I did:**

So I installed OpenAL from the official installation source. This installer copies the `OpenAL32.dll` files into the `System32` and `SysWow64` folders.

As my application is 32-bit I needed to copy `OpenAL32.dll` from SysWow64 folder into my executable directory. Once I uninstalled OpenAL (which removed these `.dll` files from my Windows `System32` and `SysWow64` folders, it worked with the `.dll` file accompanied with my executable file.

Comment: Sorry for being 2 years late, but if you're using OpenAL-soft, you shouldn't install the non-soft version (which is what places dlls into `C:\Windows`). Instead, just use the OpenAL-soft dll.

Answer (score 0):

Install Nuget package [OpenAL.Soft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenAL.Soft/1.19.1), this package includes 32 and 64 bits windows dlls, import librairies and header files. You won't need Windows directory dlls anymore.

You can also use [Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fody/6.8.0) in combinaison with [Costura.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/5.7.0) to embed all nuget and referenced assemblies to your application.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35265946)